# Input fields not working properly

Tags: html

I am trying to make a login form. But the text and password field of that form is not working properly. I have tested the code in all major browsers but different browser's giving different output. Firefox shows my password field is already filled, chrome shows both of the input fields are filled but IE shows it perfectly.  I have already used "autocomplete" attribute. But it didn't change anything. Can anyone help me to get rid of this annoying problem? My html code-

```
<form method="POST">
User Name : <input class="form" type="text" name="text" id="username" maxlength="100" size="20">
Password : <input class="form" name="password" type="password" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

screen shots:- [firefox,chrome,IE]

[image: In Mozilla Firefox]
[image: In Goole Crome-]
[image: In IE]

Comment: clear your browser cache and check!!

Comment: i already did it for several times

Comment: I don't see the `autocomplete` attribute in your HTML.

Comment: my mistake.. i forgot to add it in here.. but i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In terms of chrome:

You've saved the username and password. It's prepopullated by chrome. That's why its showing that way.

> Regarding firefox

I guess you've saved password here again. Because i've tested it in firefox and it's rendering properly. Else you've set the `value` attribute.

From settings, remove saved password for your page and try.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you have written is invalid and has unclosed elemens, your input fields should end with `\>` making your code look as follows:

```
<form method="POST">
User Name : <input class="form" type="text" name="text" id="username" maxlength="100" size="20"/>
Password : <input class="form" name="password" type="password" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Since you were not closing the input fields, your browser would automatically close them on your behalf, I would imagine that it has closed them after the `<br>` tags and therefore rendering them as the value of the input field.

Comment: Actually, no. HTML5 does not require self-closing/void elements to be closed at the end—and that behavior of closing self-closing/void elements with `/>` is inherited from the days of XHTML. This would have no impact on the autocomplete functionality of the browser—but if and only if the OP is using the HTML5 doctype.